# How can I ignore SyntaxError of 'continue' not being properly in loop in Python if I have it inside of defined function that is only called in loops?

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following code:

```
def SomeFunction():
    *some code*
    if *some condition*:
        SomeFunction() # it being recursive is the only reason why it's a separate #function
    else:
        *some other code*
        continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while *some other condition*:
        SomeFunction()
```

Obviously, I'm getting Syntax error even though the function is only called within a loop. Like I stated in the comment, I need to have it as a function instead of just including it into main code is because it's recursive. I also need to keep it within one file. What can I do?

---

What I am trying to do here is to increase a string representing numeric system based on alphabet letters by 1. (it's a creative task of some sort). There is a string of a constant size, of which I take `string[index]`where `index` by default is the last symbol of the string and change it value (take `string[:index]` and add the new value, to be specific). Unless it's already at its max value, in which case I set it to my equivalent of 0, decrease `index` by 1, and increase that unless it's at its max value as well, and here recursion begins. The `continue` is for when I reach the first symbol, aka when the string is at its max value. The system itself is neither decimal nor binary.

Comment: In the example given, the “continue” will happen automatically.

Comment: Does `SomeFunction()` return a value?

Comment: @s3cur3 Sorry I didn't specify the function given clear enough. Edited.

Comment: @Nick No, it does not

Comment: A "continue" just can't be used in this way, only directly in the loop.

Comment: Syntactic usage of `continue` aside, the function shouldn't know whether it is being called from a loop or not, and certainly shouldn't know enough about the context in which it is being called to alter the flow of the loop. The *caller* should decide, based on the result of the function, whether the loop should continue or not.

Comment: Are the two instances of "*some condition*" the same? Then this looks like a poorly defined function boundary.

Comment: [Please give the whole picture and the real problem you are solving. What you are asking for looks like a strange problem to want to solve and/or an inadequate solution to something else.](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev no, they're not, used this style of description to simplify, edited.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev sorry for taking so long, done.

Comment: Don't ignore errors. Fix them!

Comment: As I thought, the outer loop seems like a part of the algorithm so it should be inside the function. And it should probably be `while True:` with a finishing condition checked at some further step according to the algorithm and calling `break` if it's satisfied.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `SomeFunction` doesn't presently return a value, you could get it to return one to indicate whether to continue the loop:

```
def SomeFunction():
    *some code*
    if *some condition*:
        SomeFunction() # it being recorsive is the only reason why it's a separate #function
    else:
        *some other code*
        return True
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while *some other condition*:
        if SomeFunction():
            continue
```